# Changing onEdit functions to timer trigger

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, triggers

I've inherited some sheets and the scripting is beyond my understanding and my research hasn't given me an answer unfortunately! I need one of the scripts to run at midnight each night instead of using the onEdit trigger. This also means that the script will need to look for all entries that meet the requirements not just the one that was last edited.

What the scripts currently do:

- On edit, function "CRMarchive" checks column 26 of sheet A, if cell edited contains "Yes", copies the whole row and pastes it to sheet B, then deletes row from sheet A.
- Also on edit, another function "Sort" will order sheet B based on the dates in column 3, latest first.

What I need the scripts to do:

- Function "CRMarchive" does the same thing but at midnight and for *any* rows on sheet A that have "Yes" in column 26.
- Function "Sort" then sorts all entries in sheet B.

I've sorta figured out that it's the active sheet/range bit that's not allowing me to use time based triggers but my messing has only yielding limited success, i.e., I can make it move one row that meets the criteria by manually firing the script but that's it.

```
function CRMarchive(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var r = s.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "Promotions/Retain" && r.getColumn() == 26 && r.getValues() == "Yes") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = "25"
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Archive - Promotions/Retain");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row); 
  }
 if(s.getName() == "Dev+Save/Int/Welc+Nurture" && r.getColumn() == 26 && r.getValue() == "Yes") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = "25"
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Archive - Dev+Save/Int/Welc+Nurture");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
 if(s.getName() == "Reactivation" && r.getColumn() == 26 && r.getValue() == "Yes") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = "25"
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Archive - Reactivation");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
 if(s.getName() == "Conversions" && r.getColumn() == 26 && r.getValue() == "Yes") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = "25"
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Archive - Conversions");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
 if(s.getName() == "VIP" && r.getColumn() == 26 && r.getValue() == "Yes") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = "25"
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Archive - VIP");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }  
 if(s.getName() == "Service" && r.getColumn() == 26 && r.getValue() == "Yes") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = "25"
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Archive - Service");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show the code of  function Sort()? Do you know how to bind time-driven triggers to your code and just do not know how to modify the code?

Comment: Hi! I've made a blank copy for context here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X_SdvfJk_9-kcyPSwjYbVhZmE04G4ya0GdDFD6ahEss/edit?usp=sharing

I know how to make the time triggers in the triggers menu and a little bit of how to make triggers in the actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### To adapt your CRMarchive function from onEdit too time-driven trigger you need to perform the following changes:

1. Instead of retrieving the active sheet, retrieve with [getSheets()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets) all sheets of the spreadsheet and loop through them (in your case you want to loop up to the 6th sheet)
2. Instead of retrieving the activeRange, retrieve the whole [dataRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange) and loop through each row, retrieving the individual cells of the range with [getCell](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getcellrow,-column)
3. Instead of verifying either the active column is 26 - just retrieve directly the value of all cells in column 26
4. No need to copy paste the lines

```
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = "25"
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Archive - Promotions/Retain");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
```

into each `if` statement - use a [switch](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp) statement to retrieve the sheet of interest and keep the other requests common for all sheets

5. After modifying the code, bing to it a time-driven trigger as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually)

**Sample:**

```
function CRMarchive(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    var s = sheets[i];
    var r = s.getDataRange();
    for (var j = 0; j < r.getLastRow(); j++){
      Logger.log(r.getCell(j+1, 26).getA1Notation());
      if(r.getCell(j+1, 26).getValue() == "Yes") {
        var row = r.getCell(j+1, 26).getRow();
        var numColumns = "25";
        switch(s.getName()) {
          case "Promotions/Retain":
            var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Archive - Promotions/Retain");
            break;
          case "Dev+Save/Int/Welc+Nurture":
            var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Archive - Dev+Save/Int/Welc+Nurture");
            break;
          case "Reactivation":
            var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Archive - Reactivation");
            break;
          case "Conversions":
            var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Archive - Conversions");
            break;
          case "VIP":
            var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Archive - VIP");
          case "Service":  
            break;            
            var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Archive - Service");
            break;
        }        
        var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
        s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
        s.deleteRow(row);         
      }
    }
  }
}``
```

Comment: This is great, thank you! I'm learning more every day and this will really help. I'm so close to getting it working, there's just a snag on line 8 apparently - "cell reference is out of range". I've made a blank copy so that it can be seen in context here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X_SdvfJk_9-kcyPSwjYbVhZmE04G4ya0GdDFD6ahEss/edit?usp=sharing

I really appreciate all the assistance - I need to get it working ASAP but after 3 days of learning/trial and error it's still just beyond me :(

Comment: Just to add, I'm not just looking for someone to fix my scripts so I'm sorry if it comes across that way. I've taken in everything from the above but the var i and var j bits are confusing me - what exactly are these bits doing?

Comment: First of all: my code has a typo, it should be `r.getCell(j+1, 26)` and not `i+1` - sorry about this. But your problem arises from the fact that not all of your sheets have a column Z, indeed you want to loop only though the first 6 sheets from what I can see from your spreadsheet. In this case you should loop with the counter variable `i` until 6. I updated my code. Important delete all empty rows - they may your code much slower.

Comment: Ah I was so close! I tried the change from i to j and tried adding a column Z to the archive sheets but not both at the same time. Only thing is it seems to stop looping after 3-4 times so if there's 5+ entries of "yes" it doesn't get them all, however! I think this is something I'd like to tackle myself, and besides I can set it to hourly for now. 
I honestly can't thank you enough. I'm going to brush up on my Google script/Java script but this has given me a real headstart!